# What determines direction in "Hatches"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, linear-referencing, streets, address

I created a route layer that uses hatches to help determine addresses along a street centerline. About 90% of the time, the hatches go up from zero in the direction that the line was digitized but about 10% of the time (+/-) the hatches go in (what I would say is) the "wrong direction". I can symbolize this layer with arrows showing the direction of the line which shows me the instances where the hatches are wrong.

What determines the direction of the hatches and can I do a better job of controlling this?

Wow hatches or hatching or centerlines are new tags ? Wish me luck with this one!

Comment: I'm guessing that the direction of hatching may be controlled by the m values of your route layer. Have you checked your m values? You should be able to look at vertices and their m values in an edit session.

Comment: I'll investigate this. I'm not familiar with the role of m values.

Answer (score 1):

Like pvdev stated, the hatches are depending on the m-values of the route.

The digitizing direction of the lines plays a no role for the creation of the m-values of the route using **LENGTH** as Measure Source for ArcGISs Create Route, as the answers to the questions below show too. Coordinate Priority is overruling digitizing direction.

To control the creation of m-values use the option **TWO_FIELDS** as **Measure Source** for the tool Create Route. Add two fields like FromField and ToField and fill FromField with 0 and the ToField with the length of the line.

Using this setting m-values will grow in digitizing direction and with them the hatches too.

[How to preserve original direction of NHD segments when creating route using gp.CreateRoutes_lr tool?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11584/how-to-preserve-original-direction-of-nhd-segments-when-creating-route-using-gp?rq=1)

[Linear Referencing using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14134/linear-referencing-using-arcgis-desktop?rq=1)